# Read specific div from HttpResponse

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

I am sending 1 httpWebRequest and reading the response.
I am getting full page in the response.
I want to get 1 div which is names ad Rate from the response.
So how can I match that pattern?

My code is like:

```
    HttpWebRequest WebReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.domain.com/");
    HttpWebResponse WebResp = (HttpWebResponse)WebReq.GetResponse();
    Stream response = WebResp.GetResponseStream();
    StreamReader data = new StreamReader(response);
    string result = data.ReadToEnd();
```

I am getting response like:

```
<HTML><BODY><div id="rate">Todays rate 55 Rs.</div></BODY></HTML>
```

I want to read data of div rate. i.e. I should get Content "Todays rate 55 Rs."

So how can I make regex for this???

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [HTML Agility Pack](http://html-agility-pack.net/?z=codeplex) can load and parse the file for you, no need for messy streams and responses:

```
HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
HtmlDocument doc = web.Load("http://jsbin.com/owobe3");
HtmlNode rateNode = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@id='rate']");
string rate = rateNode.InnerText;
```

Comment: What if adding a library to the solution is not an option? Should we go towards dirty text processing ways?

Comment: @AleX - If all you need is to read a simple value from a page, text processing is probably your most practical option. Writing a full HTML parser is also possible (there are language definitions available), but I wouldn't do it unless required.

Answer (score 4):

You should read the entire response and then use something like the [Html Agility Pack](http://html-agility-pack.net/?z=codeplex) to parse the response and extract the bits you want in an xpath-like syntax:

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(result);
var output = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@id='rate']").InnerHtml;
```

**Dont** use regular expressions!

Answer (score 0):

If you have only one Todays rate text then you can do it like this:

```
Todays rate \d+ Rs.
```

In other case you can add div tag in your regex.
Edit: Sorry, haven't installed regex locally
You need to use grouping and get value from the group. It will look like this

```
<div id="rate">(?<group>[^<])</div>
```

Don't know if it works, however use this idea.