# Get data from html <Div> to wp7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, html

Is it possible to go to a webpage and get the text in a div tag to a .cs file in my wp7 project?

I found this post [Read specific div from HttpResponse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5075104/read-specific-div-from-httpresponse) and this works for a regular Windows Forms Project but not Windows Phone, anyone know how to do this in a wp7 project?

Comment: There _are_ builds of HTML Agility Pack that could work on WP7... have you tried using it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) (also found [on NuGet](http://nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack))

Comment: Thanks that worked but thats strange in the linc that i posted they alsoe used HtmlAgilityPack and i downloaded the Html Agility Pack and when I tried to add the package it said that this did now work with wp7. But well thanks!